# Error with rounding extension on decimal - cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, extension-methods, rounding

I've used extension methods numerous times, and haven't run into this issue. Anyone have any ideas why this is throwing an error?

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Rounds the specified value.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
 /// <param name="decimals">The decimals.</param>
 /// <returns></returns>
 public static decimal Round (this decimal value, int decimals)
 {
     return Math.Round(value, decimals);
 }
```

Usage:

```
decimal newAmount = decimal.Parse("3.33333333333434343434");
this.rtbAmount.Text = newAmount.Round(3).ToString();
```

newAmount.Round(3) is throwing the compiler error:

```
Error   1   Member 'decimal.Round(decimal)' cannot be accessed with an instance     reference; qualify it with a type name instead
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The conflict here is a conflict between your extension method and [`decimal.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4e2bye2.aspx). The simplest fix here, as already discovered, is to use a different name. Methods on the type *always* take precedence over extension methods, even to the point of conflicting with `static` methods.

Comment: Thanks! Also, see [Geert Verhoeven](http://geertverhoeven.blogspot.com/)'s [Strange behavior with extension methods](http://geertverhoeven.blogspot.com/2008/01/strange-behavior-with-extension-methods.html).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for answering my own question so fast. Within a second of posting this, it dawned on me that perhaps the compiler didn't like "Round" as the name. So I changed it to "RoundNew" and it worked. Some sort of naming conflict I guess...'

No errors anymore:

```
/// <summary>
/// Rounds the specified value.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The value.</param>
/// <param name="decimals">The decimals.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static decimal RoundNew (this decimal value, int decimals)
{
    return Math.Round(value, decimals);
}

decimal newAmount = decimal.Parse("3.33333333333434343434");
this.rtbAmount.Text = newAmount.RoundNew(3).ToString();
```

Comment: Is it possible, that naming the extension method "Round" somehow conflicts with the Math.Round method? This seems more like an error with the compiler than a true error.

Comment: The conflict is decimal.Round: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4e2bye2.aspx - it is not a compiler error

Comment: Oh, I totally overlooked that. Please post an answer so I may give you credit.