# decimal extension method error after .net core 2.0 update

Tags: .net-core-2.0

I have following extension methods class for doubles and decimals.
The compiler gives me an error for the call of

```
number.Round(2)
number.Round(3)
```

within the decimal methods but does not complain about the same methods for the double values.
Any idea why?

Here is the code... easy to reproduce...

```
public static class NumberExtensions
{
    public static double Round(this double number, int decimals)
    {
        return Math.Round(number, decimals);
    }

    public static double Round3(this double number)
    {
        return number.Round(3);
    }

    public static double Round2(this double number)
    {
        return number.Round(2);
    }

    public static decimal Round(this decimal number, int decimals)
    {
        return Math.Round(number, decimals);
    }

    public static decimal Round3(this decimal number)
    {
        return number.Round(3);
    }

    public static decimal Round2(this decimal number)
    {
        return number.Round(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reported error is:

> Error CS0176  Member 'decimal.Round(decimal)' cannot be accessed with
>   an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Possible cause & solution: [Error with rounding extension on decimal - cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044520/error-with-rounding-extension-on-decimal-cannot-be-accessed-with-an-instance-r)

**Update:**

with .net core version < 2.0, the following statment:

```
decimal.Round(3);
```

> Error CS0117  'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'Round'

but with .net core 2.0 its valid statement since it cover much more of .NET Framework compared to prior .net core releases,

below quoted from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/ :

> We have more than doubled the set of available APIs in .NET Standard
>   from 13k in .NET Standard 1.6 to 32k in .NET Standard 2.0. Most of the
>   added APIs are .NET Framework APIs

Comment: Thanks for checking, but if I just change my target framework from .NET Core 2.0 --> .NET Core 1.1 then the build is successful without error. So... I don't understand why it works in 1.1 but not 2.0... and the second thing: why does only the line with decimal throw an error in .NET Core 2.0... but the code lines with doubles just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okey got it.

In .NET Core there has been added a static method in decimal also naming "Round"... so that's the conflict.